# getPlaceByID() always fails with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer is closed

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm using Google Places API, and I need to retrieve Place Details using Place ID. I'm trying to invoke method `getPlaceById()`, but it always fails. Here's the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer is closed.
at com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder.zzg(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.data.zzc.zzcB(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzt.zzG(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzb.getPlaceId(Unknown Source)
at .onPredictionSelected(CreateLocationActivity.java:181)
at .AutocompletePredictionsHelper.onItemClick(AutocompletePredictionsHelper.java:51)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:905)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$400(AutoCompleteTextView.java:90)
at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1195)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1247)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3215)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4009)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

My code:

```
public void onPredictionSelected(AutocompletePrediction prediction) {
    if (!googleApiClient.isConnected()) return;
    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> result =
            Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, prediction.getPlaceId());
    result.setResultCallback(places -> {
        if (places.getCount() > 0)
            place = places.get(0);
        places.release();
    });
}
```

It's quite strange, because Google Places API has been connected properly.
What could be possible reason of this exception?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to continue using the object contained in the buffer after you've released the buffer, call `freeze()` on the object before calling `release()`

> You can use `isDataValid()` at any time to determine if the object is available or not. For example, `place.isDataValid()` returns true before the call to `buffer.release()` and false afterwards. Note that `frozen.isDataValid()` returns true both before and after the buffer has been released.

**Reference** https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/buffers

Comment: thanks for your answer. 
Looks like `AutocompletePredictionBuffer.release()` has beed invoked before my  `onPredictionSelected()` method.
That's why buffer was closed =)

Answer (score 2):

A good way to start is by Logging what's going on. You can validate if the result of the operation was successful by refactoring your if-statement like this:

```
if (places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.getCount() > 0)
```

Check the message of the status for further information:

```
String msg = places.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
Log.e(<some TAG>, "Status message: " + msg);
```

Then simply check the LogCat for the status message. That's not a real answer but it would definitely give you some clues on how to proceed.